# Liferay install portlet war from eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, installation, portlet, liferay-6

Liferay porlets how to install from eclipse with maven.

I am following instructions from porlets in action book, i have maven configured eclipse project which i wants to install into liferay portal server. I found examples on liferay website which shows having eclipse liferay ide plugin they install portlets with one click. But i don't want to use liferay ide plugin instead porlets in action books gives me steps how to setup liferay bundle tomcat into eclipse tomcat plugin; but it does not have instructions that how can I install my portlets war into tomcat to execute the portlet. I tried running as tomcat configuration which I configured with liferay tomcat but my portlet didn't appear into portal sever. any help appreciated.

Comment: why not just copy/paste the .war file in tomcat/deploy folder? it should get auto-deployed

Comment: yes i have figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy/paste the .war file in liferay-portal-home/deploy  folder